# SDL_gfx on Windows for Haskell SDL-gfx library?

Tags: haskell, sdl, ghc, cabal

Trying to install the SDL-gfx library on Windows, and running into problems at the configure:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring SDL-gfx-0.6.0...
checking for sdl-config... /usr/bin/sdl-config
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for SDL_initFramerate in -lSDL_gfx... no
configure: error: *** SDL_gfx lib not found! Get SDL_gfx from
http://www.ferzkopp.net/~aschiffler/Software/SDL_gfx-2.0/
```

The link is broken, but I got the tar from http://www.ferzkopp.net/joomla/content/view/19/14/ and looked at the contents.  It's a grab bag of header files, c files, etc.  I'm not sure where to put these so that SDL-gfx's configure recognizes them.  For fun I also grabbed some pre-compiled dll's and header files but I don't know where to put those either.

Anyone know where I should put those files to make them work?

I had similar struggles with SDL, but I eventually found an SDL download with an "include" and "lib" directory, and added them to extra-include-dirs and extra-lib-dirs in my .cabal/config...but I don't know what is "include" and what is "lib" for SDL_gfx.

Comment: I tried to use SDL port year ago, but I wasn't lucky enough to make it work. All in all, it was easier to write my own statically-linked binding to SFML (I didn't test it on windows though).

Comment: I see there is another SFML binding on hackage already. I'd suggest to consider using SFML instead of SDL. The advantage is following: its license allow static linkage, and this eliminates certain technical issues.

Comment: @user3974391 thanks for the suggestion, i'll seriously look into it.  this SDL thing has been a bit of a headache.  Is SFML as compatible as SDL is, generally speaking?  Granted they are both just wrappers over OpenGL, right?

Comment: SDL is not a wrapper around OpenGL. It just does platform-dependent initialization and event handling stuff. And, AFAIR, SDL_gfx is (or was?) built upon older-than-feudalism blitting techniques. SFML wraps the same platform-dependent things, but its 2D library is built upon OpenGL, so it likely to be faster.